# Binding multiple mediaplayers to multiple keys C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player

So, I'm trying to build kind of a sampler. Just for fun. I'm kinda at a loss here;
I've created a grid of 4x4 in wpf and filled them with buttons. Each button has a corresponding mediaplayer (so they would not cut off the other audio when triggered)
I've added a clickevent for each button and a keydown event as wel. Now, the click events all work fine. But the keydown event only works for the last button I clicked on. The rest is unresponsive. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

a keydown event:

```
    private void Pad_1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.NumPad7)
        {
            playPad(mediaPlayer1, mp1);

        }
    }
```

and my playPad method:

```
    public void playPad(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, string mp)
    {
        if (mp != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(mp));
            mediaPlayer.Play();
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `PreviewKeyDown` event rather than `KeyDown`. BTW, there is nothing to do with binding nor MediaPlayer.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! It sorta works now, I just need to click on 1 button and then I can control the rest via keys.